# не могу понять как используя шаблоны в стандарт ml сравнить 2 списка

Tags: list, рекурсия

мне нужно сравнить 2 списка не используя стандартных функций по типу map и тд,можно использовать только шаблоны,и пролема в том что еще запрещено брать hd and tl в данном контексте задачи я джае не знаю как перебирать элементы ,помогите!!!

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде:

```
fun cmp([], []) = 0
  | cmp(xs, []) = 1
  | cmp([], ys) = -1
  | cmp(x::xs, y::ys) = if x > y then 1
                        else if x < y then -1
                        else then cmp(xs, ys)
```

Не имею возможности проверить, с sml столкнулся впервые)